# nginx rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I'm trying to implement `nginx` rewrite rules for the following situtation :
- Request `/testfa/styles/style.css` should be redirected to `/testfa/templates/styles/style.css`
I've enabled rewrite logging for my server, created following rules:

```
location /testfa {     
  rewrite ^/styles/(.+)?$ /testfa/templates/styles/$1 last;
}
```

but when I'm trying to perform request, I'm getting 404 error from server, and log file doesn't contain any info about rewriting, only following message:

```
open() "......../testfa/styles/style.css" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

What is the correct way to perform such a rewrite for `nginx` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
location /testfa/ {
    rewrite ^/testfa/styles/(.+)$ /testfa/templates/styles/$1 last;
}
```

does this work for you ?

my tested virtual >

```
server {
    listen          ...ip...:80;
    server_name     sub.domain.com;
    root            /usr/local/www/test;
    error_log       /usr/local/www/test/error_debug.log debug;

    rewrite_log     on;

    location /testfa/ {
        rewrite ^/testfa/styles/(.+)$ /testfa/templates/styles/$1 last;
    }
}
```

this works. even log has reported :

```
2011/11/25 01:06:52 [notice] 35208#0: *456705 rewritten data: "/testfa/templates/styles/test.css", args: "", client: IP, server: sub.domain.com, request: "GET /testfa/styles/test.css HTTP/1.1", host: "sub.domain.com"
```

Comment: No, still no luck - same "No such file or directory" in log, no rewrite info in log present.

Comment: i tried it on my own nginx server, and it works. can you paste all your virtual host rules?

Comment: Main config:   `server { 
     listen 80;
     index index.php index.html;
      server_name dev.example.com;
     root /var/www/www.example.com/www_dev;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.dev.log debug;
     rewrite_log on;
     include conf.d/dev_rules.inc;
    }`   Include file:  `location /testfa/ {
    rewrite ^/testfa/styles/(.+)$ /testfa/templates/styles/$1 last;
}`

Comment: can you try absolute path for include file?

Comment: i have updated my answer above, better preview. it works, tested it on my nginx 1.0.8

Comment: hehe, it happens. for config reload you do not need to restart, use "reload" attribute, and "configtest" before ;-)

Comment: Did configtest - forgot the reload.

Comment: `error_log <log_file> notice;` instead of `debug` will only output the rewrite statement and skip 50-70 lines of mostly irrelevant low-level debug info (e.g. SSL and gzip details).